# Using Java to solve `Rectangle Area` in leetcode

Tags: java

**Question:**

Find the total area covered by two rectilinear rectangles in a 2D plane.

Each rectangle is defined by its bottom left corner and top right corner as shown in the figure.
[image: pic]

**Code:**

```
public class Solution {
    public int computeArea(int A, int B, int C, int D, int E, int F, int G, int H) {
         int sum=(C - A) * (D - B) + (H - F) * (G - E);
         int shadow=Math.max((Math.min(G, C) - Math.max(A, E)), 0) * Math.max((Math.min(D, H) - Math.max(B, F)), 0);
         return sum-shadow;
    }
}
```

Just as you seen, I wrote Java code to solve this question. But I don't know why I can't pass one test.

```
Input:
-1500000001
0
-1500000000
1
1500000000
0
1500000001
1


Output:
-1294967294

Expected:
2
```

I use python to implement the same method and it works fine. I don't know why Java version can't pass this test.Can anybody tell me why？

Another version:

```
public class Solution {
    public int computeArea(int A, int B, int C, int D, int E, int F, int G, int H) {
        int area1 = (C-A) * (D-B);
        int area2 = (G-E) * (H-F);

        int overlapRegion = overlap(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H);
        return area1 + area2 - overlapRegion;
    }

    private int overlap(int A, int B, int C, int D, int E, int F, int G, int H) {
        int h1 = Math.max(A, E);
        int h2 = Math.min(C, G);
        int h = h2 - h1;

        int v1 = Math.max(B, F);
        int v2 = Math.min(D, H);
        int v = v2 - v1;

        if(h<=0 || v<=0) return 0;
        else return h*v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java doesn't have unsigned values, the sum has overflown and gone into negatives. Use `long` instead of `int` to get some more space for your number.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw another version of this code in Java but it works fine and doesn't use `long`. Why? I  added the code as supplement to my question.

Comment: Presumably because it does things in different order or different way so that the overflow doesn't happen. Run them through a debugger to see what happens.

Comment: I believe this line in the other version does the trick: `if(h<=0 || v<=0) return 0;`. In case one of the subtractions has underflown, this makes sure the overlap is set to 0 instead of multiplying a negative number. I don’t see the same in your code.

Comment: @OleV.V. You're right, it's not even an overflow issue. I didn't notice he doesn't consider negative values. Could you write an answer so I can delete this one.

Comment: It’s an overflow issue alright. You do -1500000000 - 1500000000, the correct difference would be -3000000000, but due to overflow (underflow), the result is 1294967296. The other version that the OP claimed did the right thing, returns -1294967294 too, so it has the same issue. It was me who was wrong.

Comment: Well...let's keep this then :)

Comment: But I've used `Math.max` to compare the value with 0 so that if the value is smaller than 0, then it'll use 0 to do plus operation. Why does it not work at all?

Comment: @Ole V.V. 
But I've used Math.max to compare the value with 0 so that if the value is smaller than 0, then it'll use 0 to do plus operation. Why does it not work at all?

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit Did you fix the overflow yet?

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit, 1294967296 is not smaller than 0. Not even when -3000000000 is. ;-) I’m not saying my explanation is 100 % to the point, precise and correct — but I believe I’m on the right idea. Now. If you want to know more, use a debugger or fill in `System.out.println()` calls in the code.